# Captivate - framework issue

Tags: android

I am a Android developer need quick help on a strange issue with Samsung Captivate. I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for an activity which has a list of EditText in it. The page can expand by adding more EditText views, when it grows long and onFocus of last field soft keyboard pops up and the activity doesn't completely push up. So the EditText view falls behind the soft keyboard.

The strange thing is same the activity and same code moves up without any issues for all other Android devices like HTC Aria, Xeperia, etc. Only Samsung Captivate doesn't move up completely, not sure why its device specific. Is it a framework issue?

With regards,
Visva